# Does "provides" in Dafny misbehaves and reveals the value of a variable in a print statement?

Tags: dafny

According to the Dafny reference manual: "When a name is exported as provided, then inside a module that has imported the name only the name is known, not the details of the name’s declaration." However, when I run the following code, the verifier doesn't complain,

```
module A { 
  export A provides a
  const a := 10;
}
module B {
  import opened Z = A`A
  method {:main} bValue() {
    //assert Z.a == 10;
    print Z.a,"\n"; 
  }
}
```

The behavior to **assert Z.a == 10;** complies with **provides** definition. Shouldn't
the verifier complain about **print Z.a** as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The verifier only verifies what it is being asked.
Compiled code can always call a method even though its body is always opaque.
Similarly, compiled code can always call an `opaque function`, and a function that was only provided.
Provided means that its definition is hidden ***to the verifier***, so it's an uninterpreted constant/function.
The compiler does not care about access rights.

Comment: That's clear, thanks. "The verifier does not care about access rights." I guess you mean the compiler!